# OCaml bindings for Z3: Success in OCaml interpreter, but fail in OCaml compiler

Tags: ocaml, z3

I got some problems between OCaml interpreter and OCaml compiler. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

I have just compiled successfully the OCaml bindings for Z3 following by the instructions at https://github.com/polazarus/z3-installer. They use an old Z3 version: 4.1

First, I change the file Makefile.ocaml:

```
# Findlib package installation obtion, for instance -destdir /usr/lib/ocaml
OCAMLFIND_INSTALL_FLAGS = -destdir /home/maidinh/.opam/4.01.0/lib/
```

Then, I compile it:

```
sudo apt-get install camlidl
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I don't know why it fails when run 'make' without 'sudo' permission:

- the terminal log when I run 'sudo make' : http://pastebin.com/rhdAMJKf
- the log when I run only 'make' : http://pastebin.com/qvhysRum, it says that "ld: cannot find -lcamlidl" (Can anyone explain this problem to me?)

Finally, I test the OCaml bindings for Z3 by running the OCaml interpreter 4.01.0:

```
./ocaml
#use "topfind";;
#require "z3";;
open Z3;;
Z3.mk_context;;
- : (string * string) list -> Z3.context = <fun>
```

Successfully!

---

However, my program failed to run using OCaml compiler. This is my program:

```
let _ = print_endline "Start" in
let _ = Z3.mk_context [] in 
()
```

Then, I compile and run:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package z3 -c main.ml -o main.cmo
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package z3 -o main  main.cmo
./main
Start
Error: internal error
```

Can anyone explain the error to me? Thank you so much!

Comment: OCaml, not Ocaml. Please.

Comment: I am so sorry. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Did you try the new binding that comes with the latest Z3 (http://z3.codeplex.com/) rather that this old script (I can say it I wrote it)? IMO you should try to install camlidl with opam too, rather than sudo-ing anything.

Comment: Yes, I tried with the latest Z3 at z3.codeplex.com, but it's fail to compile. I also installed camlidl already. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, Z3 4.1's ML binding is buggy. I revert it back to 4.0 on the repository of z3-installer. To compile:

```sh
ocamlfind remove z3
opam install camlidl
git clone https://github.com/polazarus/z3-installer.git # fresh clean install
cd z3-installer
make
sudo make lib-install
make ocaml-install
```

Note that the API is slightly different, your example should read:

```ml
let _ = print_endline "Start" in
let _ = Z3.mk_context_x [||] in 
()
```

To install and compile the new Z3 with ML bindings, you should have a look at [Drup's Z3 overlay](https://github.com/Drup/ocaml-z3). He explains how to compile Z3.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already tried the Drup's Z3 overlay, but I don't know how to use it. I followed his manual: download the Z3 official source (both master and ml-ng branch), then run make successfully. However I don't know how to use his code, should I copy his code to somewhere? What does the overlay mean?

Comment: Ah, did you say that you has just updated your project by using Z3 4.0? Oke, I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This script was intended for the old OCaml API of Z3. So it can only go back in time :/ I did not get a thorough look at the new API, but at first glance a lot have changed in both the interface and the build process. If I have the time someday... But in the meantime this should work but will not enjoy the many improvements done on Z3 since then.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me more about the Drup's Z3 overlay? I tried anyway but fail all.

Comment: No I did not try it in any way. You should try to contact Drup directly.